# Mysql find rows equal to some values but limited by count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a conversation app where users are assigned to conversations.
One conversation can have 1, 2 or more participants, I use a table to link users to conversations :

[image]

When user 5 wants to initiate a new conversation with user 6, I don't want to create a new conversation because user 5 and 6 already have an ongoing conversation_id.

They actually also have a different group conversation with user 10

I have 2 parameters : it's **user 5** that wants to speak to **user 6**
How can I query this table to find if a conversation exists **only between these 2 users**?

I tried this :

```
SELECT *,count(id) FROM `conversation_members`
WHERE user_id IN (5,6)
GROUP BY `conversation_id`
```

[image]

But

- This also returns conversation id 2, while I would like to have
  only id 1, so I would like to limit the select query to elements
  having a count of 2, If I do the group by before I lose the ability
  to match the users.
- This also returns id 7 because it matches 1 of the 2 user_ids
  it should match both

In the end I just want to retrieve ID 1 as this is the conversation **including** user 5 and 6 and **nobody else**. Is this possible only with a Mysql Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_members
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING SUM(user_id IN (5, 6)) = 2 AND
       COUNT(*) = 2;
```

This will return all conversations (if any) that have exactly those members.

Comment: nice and easy, hope it's bulletproof in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Use the sum of a case expression along with the count in the having clause:

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_members
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING SUM(case when user_id IN (5, 6) then 1 end) = 2 
AND COUNT(*) = 2;
```

The ability to use this `HAVING SUM(user_id IN (5, 6)) = 2` is not common and is a "MySQL curiosity" I believe. So I suggest you use a case expression instead which I think is also easier to read/understand.